# Check for new messages with SQL [facebook like chat]

Tags: sql

I'm currently developing a facebook like chat for my website. Right now I am asking myself, **what is the best way (the best sql query) to check for new messages?**
My tables look like this:

**messages**

```
messageID   | userID    | roomID    | message   | time
-----------------------------------------------------------
 4          | 1         | 1         | test      | 1369062603 
 9          | 2         | 1         | great     | 1369062609
```

**rooms**

```
roomID  | host  | createTime
-----------------------------
 1      | 1     | 1369062600
```

**room_to_user**

```
roomID  | userID 
----------------
 1      | 1     
 1      | 2
```

I plan to add group chatting that's why I don't want to add a sepereate **read** column to my message table.
My next attempt would be a sql query filtered by the time **column**.

What would be your attempt? Thanks!

Comment: Please provide a specific technical issue you're having.

Comment: The issue is how to check for new messages without having a **read** column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Will this work?

```
Select m.*
From messages m join rooms r on m.roomID = r.roomID
    join room_to_user ru on r.roomID = ru.roomID
where ru.userID = @userID and m.time > @timeSinceLastRead
```

You didn't specify which SQL you're using (Sql Server? Oracle? MySql?) and you'll probably have to play with the format for m.time.